# jquery mouseover / mouseout to change scroll position

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and I am struggling with the following:

**From research I have come up with a quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkhbcxzw/14/). It's not quite working yet, what I would like to achieve is:**

I want 'Link30' to go to the top when I mouseover 'DIV 1' (and for 'Link30' to remain at the top on mouseout).

Then I want 'Link50' to go to the top when I mouseover 'DIV 2' (and for 'Link50' to remain at the top on mouseout).

I want to mouseover the divs any number of times and still have the relevant links go to the top of the scrolling div each time.

At the moment you mouseover 'DIV 1' and 'Link30' goes to the top however then when you mouseover 'DIV 2' it stays at 'Link30' rather than moving to 'Link50' as I would like.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Here is a sample of my code but you are best seeing the **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkhbcxzw/14/)**.

```
$( "div.overout1" )

.mouseover(function() {
$( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse over " );
$('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === 'Link30';    }).addClass('on');
var offset = $('.on').offset().top - $('.links').scrollTop();
if(offset > window.innerHeight)
    {
    $('.links').scrollTop(offset);
    }
})

.mouseout(function() {
$( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse out " );
$('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === 'Link30'; }).removeClass('on');
});

$( "div.overout2" )

.mouseover(function() {
$( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse over " );
$('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === 'Link50'; }).addClass('on');
var offset = $('.on').offset().top - $('.links').scrollTop();
if(offset > window.innerHeight)
    {
    $('.links').scrollTop(offset);
    }
})

.mouseout(function() {
$( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse out " );
$('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === 'Link50'; }).removeClass('on');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat optimised version :

https://jsfiddle.net/fkhbcxzw/15/

```
linkScroll($('div.overout1'), 'Link30');
linkScroll($('div.overout2'), 'Link50');

function linkScroll(item, identify) {

    var object;

    item
    .on('mouseenter touchstart', function() {

        object = $(this).find('span');
        object.text('mouseenter-touchstart');
        $('a').removeClass('on').filter(function() {return $(this).text() === identify}).addClass('on');

        var offset = $('.on').position().top;
        var current = $('.links').scrollTop();
        $('.links').scrollTop(current+offset);
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {

        object.text('mouseleave');
    });
}
```

Because only a single action is needed on entering each div, it's better to use `mouseenter` which only fires on the parent. The `mouseover` events keeps unnecessarily firing as long as you're hovering. Also added some mobile support.

Comment: Thanks @Shikkediel, I found your answer the most helpful in solving the original problem. It worked perfectly for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you use a class for the positions you want to scroll to together with some flags e.g on/off.

**Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/jc8aqz65/

**Script**

```
var tclass;
var cla = 0;
var clab = 0;
var topa = $('.30').position().top - 10;
var topb = $('.50').position().top - 10;
$(".overout1, .overout2").mouseover(function () {
    tclass = $(this).attr("class")
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse over ");
    if (cla == 0 && tclass == "overout1") {
        $('.links').animate({
            scrollTop: topa
        }, 500);
        cla = 1;
    } else if (clab == 0 && tclass == "overout2") {
        $('.links').animate({
            scrollTop: topb
        }, 500);
        clab = 1;
    }
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse out ");
    if (tclass == "overout1") {
        clab = 0;
    } else {
        cla = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Shikkediel i actually voted for you, not sure why it down-voted. Better now?

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements, you could create a **function that you can reuse** passing it different parameters ($elem as which div to apply the hover effect, and the link number for example):

Let's call the function **hoverLink** for instance.

You could this in so many ways but modifying quickly your code...

**

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    var hoverLink = function($elem, link) {

        $elem.hover(function() {
            var offset = $('.links').position().top;
            $('a').removeClass('on');

            $('a').filter(function(index) {
                return $(this).text() === 'Link' + link;
            }).addClass('on');

            offset = $('.on').position().top;
            $('.links').scrollTop(offset);

        });
    };
    var div = $('.overout1');
    var div2 = $('.overout2');
    var div3 = $('.overout3');

    hoverLink(div, 10);
    hoverLink(div2, 25);
    hoverLink(div3, 50);
});
```

```css
html,body{height:100%;}
.overout1,.overout2,.overout3 {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    float: left;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:helvetica;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
  }
.overout1 {
    background-color: green;
  } 
.overout2 {
    background-color: blue;
  } 
.overout3 {
    background-color: red;
  } 
.links{
    width: 40%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:helvetica;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;    
}
 
  p,span {
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
  }
.on {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div class="overout1">
       <p>DIV 1</p>
      <span>move your mouse</span>
</div>
<div class="overout2">
        <p>DIV 2</p>
      <span>move your mouse</span>
</div>
<div class="overout3">
        <p>DIV 3</p>
      <span>move your mouse</span>
</div>

<div class="links">
<a href="#">Link1</a><br />
<a href="#">Link2</a><br />
<a href="#">Link3</a><br />
<a href="#">Link4</a><br />
<a href="#">Link5</a><br />
<a href="#">Link6</a><br />
<a href="#">Link7</a><br />
<a href="#">Link8</a><br />
<a href="#">Link9</a><br />
<a href="#">Link10</a><br />
<a href="#">Link11</a><br />
<a href="#">Link12</a><br />
<a href="#">Link13</a><br />
<a href="#">Link14</a><br />
<a href="#">Link15</a><br />
<a href="#">Link16</a><br />
<a href="#">Link17</a><br />
<a href="#">Link18</a><br />
<a href="#">Link19</a><br />
<a href="#">Link20</a><br />
<a href="#">Link21</a><br />
<a href="#">Link22</a><br />
<a href="#">Link23</a><br />
<a href="#">Link24</a><br />
<a href="#">Link25</a><br />
<a href="#">Link26</a><br />
<a href="#">Link27</a><br />
<a href="#">Link28</a><br />
<a href="#">Link29</a><br />
<a href="#">Link30</a><br />
<a href="#">Link31</a><br />
<a href="#">Link32</a><br />
<a href="#">Link33</a><br />
<a href="#">Link34</a><br />
<a href="#">Link35</a><br />
<a href="#">Link36</a><br />
<a href="#">Link37</a><br />
<a href="#">Link38</a><br />
<a href="#">Link39</a><br />
<a href="#">Link40</a><br />
<a href="#">Link41</a><br />
<a href="#">Link42</a><br />
<a href="#">Link43</a><br />
<a href="#">Link44</a><br />
<a href="#">Link45</a><br />
<a href="#">Link46</a><br />
<a href="#">Link47</a><br />
<a href="#">Link48</a><br />
<a href="#">Link49</a><br />
<a href="#">Link50</a><br />
<a href="#">Link51</a><br />
<a href="#">Link52</a><br />
<a href="#">Link53</a><br />
<a href="#">Link54</a><br />
<a href="#">Link55</a><br />
<a href="#">Link56</a><br />
<a href="#">Link57</a><br />
<a href="#">Link58</a><br />
<a href="#">Link59</a><br />
<a href="#">Link60</a><br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

** https://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/fkhbcxzw/16/

Comment: *and for 'Link30' to remain at the top on mouseout*... besides that it's sort of a repetitive answer.

Comment: Sorry but i had the tab opened half an hour ago and then i started coding it and i saw those 2 answers already there :) It's a quick solution for the problem posted.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their input. They are all great answers however I found the answer from @Shikkediel the most helpful in solving the original problem.